# Dataflow writes to GCS bucket, but timestamp in filename is unchanged

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, apache-beam, dataflow, bucket

I have a question on Apache Beam, especially on dataflow.

I have a pipeline which reads from a cloudsql database and writes to GCS. The filename has a timestamp in it. I expect that each time I run it, it will generate a file with a different timestamp in it.

I tested on my local machine. Beam reads from a postgres db and writes to a file (instead of gcs). It works fine. The files generated have different timestamps in it. Like

```
jdbc_output.csv-00000-of-00001_2020-08-19_00:11:17.csv

jdbc_output.csv-00000-of-00001_2020-08-19_00:25:07.csv
```

However, when I deploy to Dataflow, trigger it via Airflow (we have airflow as scheduler), the filename it generates always uses the same timestamp. The timestamp is unchanged even if I run it multiple times. The timestamp is very close to the time when the dataflow template was uploaded.

Here is the simple code to write.

```
output.apply("Write to Bucket", TextIO.write().to("gs://my-bucket/filename").withNumShards(1)
      .withSuffix("_" +  String.valueOf(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())).replace(" ","_") +".csv"));
```

I'd like to know the reason why dataflow does not use the current time in the filename, instead it uses the timestamp when the template file was uploaded.

Further, how to solve this issue? My plan is to run the dataflow each day, and expecting a new file with a different timestamp in it.

Comment: Do you use Dataflow template right? And why do you use Dataflow instead of BigQuery for this? Do you have multiple sink? Multiple sources?

Comment: Yes I use dataflow template. I have one source, that is cloudsql, and one sink, that is gcs. I plan to run the dataflow job daily, to copy data from a table to a bucket. The filename should have a timestamp in it, to avoid overwrite. I know there are other options to do this task, but I'd like to know why my solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition (because I never tested it) is that the template creation start your pipeline and take a snapshot of it. Therefore, your pipeline is ran, your date time evaluated and kept as-is in the template. And the value never change.

The [documentation description](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/overview#templated-dataflow-jobs) also mentions that the pipeline is run before the template creation, like a compilation indeed.

> 2. Developers run the pipeline and create a template. The Apache Beam SDK stages files in Cloud Storage, creates a template file (similar to job request), and saves the template file in Cloud Storage.

To fix this, you can use `ValueProvider` interface. And, I never made the link before now, but it's in the [template section of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#runtime-parameters-and-the-valueprovider-interface)

*Note: However, the cheapest, and the easiest to maintain for simple read in Cloud SQL database and export to file, is to not use Dataflow!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I use Dataflow because of some team requirements. Your explanation is quite reasonable.
Actually I used java.util.Date().getTime() in 2 places to calculate timestamp in my code. One is in the withSuffix(), and another in 
"preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));". This is not the exact code, but quite close. I want to copy data that is less than a timestamp. Each day I run it, it should use the current timetamp. Actually it works here.
I found withSuffix() does not support ValueProvider, but to() does. I will try and let you know.